# Maximization with geometry and not calculus

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Conjecture: Given constraint $g(x,y)=0$ that implies $y=f(x)$ and a quantity we wish to maximize(minimize), $h(x,y)$, then, if h(x,y)=h(y,x), an extremum obtains when x=y. If $x>>y$ corresponds with arbitrarily large values of h, then x=y corresponds to a minimum. If $x>>y$ corresponds with arbitrarily small values, $x=y$ corresponds to a maximum.

Fermat addressed the following problem with primordial calculus: Given a line segment of length L, where should you cut it such that, were the resulting pieces to make two of the four legs of a rectangle, the area would be at a minimum?

You can do this without calculus:

Let x+y=L where x and y are to be the length and width of the rectangle, respectively. We wish to minimize xy.

The bigger x, the smaller y. Once x is greater than L/2, it starts taking on values formerly taken by y, and y now obtains those values taken by x. In either case, x+y is the same, and xy is the same, so we only need consider values of x from 0 to L/2.

These considerations suggest we take advantage of this symmetry: Let
$$x=\frac{L}{2}-q$$
$$y=\frac{L}{2}+q$$

So, for any value of q, $x+y=L$, and $$A=\frac{L^2}{4}-q^2$$.

Clearly, Area is a maximum when $q=0$.

I think there's a theorem at work here.

I understand how this works with Lagrange multipliers, but I believe this can be proven in only geometric terms, preferably with no explicit reference to the slope of tangent lines. I suspect arguments using area are possible as in the above.

Assuming this theorem is true, then in specific problems, extrema can be found without having to use a second derivative test. If symmetry is sufficiently clear, extrema can be found with a minimum of algebra.

Comment: I think you have to assume some monotonicity in your conjecture. If not, then you can write a quartic polynomial with positive leading term, symmetric about the vertical axis with a local maximum at the origin.and absolute minima to its left and right.

Comment: Interesting. I'm playing around with convexity regarding this conjecture. Monotonicity might simplify things for me.

Comment: "Extrema can be found without having to use a second derivative test" - there is no need to use second derivatives when solving optimization problems. At best, it allows you to cut down on the number of candidates. However, it is usually easier to instead just compare the function values at those candidates.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this answers your question.

Maximization with  geometry.

Let $L$ be fixed, and $x+y=L$.

Draw $|AB| =L.$

Draw the Thales circle at the midpoint $M$ of 
$\overline {AB}$. Pick any point $C$ on the circle.

Draw the height $h_{AB}$ from $C$ onto $\overline {AB},$ intersecting at point $D.$

Triangle $ABC$ is a right triangle, right angle at $C $.

$D$ divides $L$ into two parts : $|AD|=x|$ and $|DB|=y$;

$x+y=L.$

In the right  triangle $ABC$ we have

$h^2=xy$ (rule of altitudes).

$h$ is maximal for $h= |AB|/2=L/2,$ radius of the circle.

Then triangle $ABC$ is isosceles and $x=y.$

$h_{max}^2= L^2/4 $

What is $h_{min}$?

Comment: That might be a better way of expressing the specific I have in mind. It's clearer than my own.

I think there exists certain symmetry conditions that can be exploited to find extrema. Suposse XY=A. Then X+Y can be made arbitrarily large. There is no maximum. Is there a minimum? When is it safe to guess X=Y?

Well, $X+Y=A/x+x$ For any $X$, you get the same sum if you use $A/x$ instead. This suggests something special about $X=A/X$. If we let $X=q\sqrt{A}$ and $Y=\sqrt{A}/q$, we guarantee $XY=A$. We reduce the problem to having to minimize $(q+1/q)$. It acn be shown |q+1/q-1|>0 if |q-1|>0.